# ERROR: Element name=user_login not found on session a60ba70a450c48c2901bc2b5edb3d315 and Killing Firefox

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium to read values from Excel Sheet which contains 6 rows and 7 columns. I have one Java file and one Selenium File.

The following are the methods used in Selenium File

@Before
`setup()`

calling the `getDataFromExcel()` and storing it in valueMap array.

@Test
`Registration()`

Iterating the valueMap array in this function.

@After
`selenium.stop()`
`seleniumServer.stop()`

While executing the Selenium File as JUnit Test the first 2 records were executed successfully and i got the following error

Got result: ERROR: Element name=user_login not found on session
Killing Firefox...

Kindly help some one to resolve this issue so that i can proceed further.

Comment: There may be network issue. Use waitForPageToLoad();

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with .stop() causing "lost" sessions or elements.  Try using .exit() instead.